# Bot is sending embed 6 times

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots, fivem

I have this code, but the bots is sending the same embed 6 times. I generated a new token for the bot and created a new bot but the same problem.

```js
on("playerConnecting",async(name) => {
    const player = global.source;
    let discorddd = "NOT DETECTED";
    for (let i = 0; i < GetNumPlayerIdentifiers(player); i++) {
        const identifier = GetPlayerIdentifier(player, i);
        if (identifier.includes('discord:')) {
            discorddd = identifier
        }
        discorddd = discorddd.split('discord:').pop()
                let e5566 = new MessageEmbed()
                e5566.setColor("RED")
                e5566.setDescription(`${discorddd}`)
            client.channels.cache.get('1051799184803643392').send(e5566)
        
    }
})
```

I tried to use many different types of code, but I'm getting the same issues.

Answer (score -2):

You have to replace the last line with:

```js
client.channels.cache.get('1051799184803643392').send({embeds:[e5566]})
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Have you had a chance to read the question?

Comment: but he has a mistake maybe thats the problem and if that is not the answer u fix it for him

Comment: How do you know it's a mistake? Do you know what version of discord.js they're using? How could it be the problem if it's sending 6 embeds? That means `send(e5566)` clearly works. _"if that is not the answer u fix it for him"_ Thanks, but **there's no need to be disrespectful**. I've helped hundreds of people on this site. We closed this question because it was unclear and there is no way to know what's wrong without OP updating their question.